# AuraEnabled methods do not support return type of List

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to get all Knowledge DataCategories with their labels into my LWC. I found this [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_data_categories.htm). But unfortunately I get this error `AuraEnabled methods do not support return type of List<Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult>`.

I really have no idea to fix this, as I only able to write simple apex controller. Or is there a better way to get the DataCategory labels into LWC?

Any help would be so great. Thank you.

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult> describeDataCategoryGroupSample() {
    List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult> describeCategoryResult;
    try {
      //Creating the list of sobjects to use for the describe
      //call
      List<String> objType = new List<String>();

      objType.add('KnowledgeArticleVersion');

      //Describe Call
      describeCategoryResult = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups(objType);

      //Using the results and retrieving the information
      for (
        DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult singleResult : describeCategoryResult
      ) {
        //Getting the name of the category
        singleResult.getName();

        //Getting the name of label
        singleResult.getLabel();

        //Getting description
        singleResult.getDescription();

        //Getting the sobject
        singleResult.getSobject();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return describeCategoryResult;
  }
```

Comment: Better to use a custom apex class to wrap the `List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult>` and return from apex.

Comment: @Raul thank you for your response, to you have any links / resources where I get an idea how to build a suitable wrapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into the fields you need on the UI and convert that to wrapper.

Something like this:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper> describeDataCategoryGroupSample() {
    List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult> describeCategoryResult;
    List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper> describeCategoryResultWrappers = new List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper>();
    try {
        //Creating the list of sobjects to use for the describe
        //call
        List<String> objType = new List<String>();

        objType.add('KnowledgeArticleVersion');

        //Describe Call
        describeCategoryResult = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups(objType);

        for(DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult categoryGroupResult : describeCategoryResult){
            DescribeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper describeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper = new DescribeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper();
            describeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper.categoryCount = categoryGroupResult.getCategoryCount();
            describeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper.description = categoryGroupResult.getDescription();
            describeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper.name = categoryGroupResult.getName();
            describeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper.sobjectName = categoryGroupResult.getSobject();
            describeCategoryResultWrappers.add(describeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
     // catch appropriate exception and log it.
    }
    return describeCategoryResultWrappers;
}

public class DescribeDataCategoryGroupResultWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled public Integer categoryCount;
    @AuraEnabled public String description;
    @AuraEnabled public String label;
    @AuraEnabled public String name;
    @AuraEnabled public String sobjectName;
}
```

Comment: This is great stuff and works like charm - many thanks dear Nagendra. I have to dig into that in order to understand the magic behind it. But so far: simply great!!

Comment: Empty catch on generic `Exception`...very bad idea.

Comment: Correct. I just copy pasted the code given above, but will edit and write a comment.

Comment: cool, thank you!! The "final" class/method I'm referring to is [DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructures](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_data_categories.htm). I faced some problems with getting the e.g. the  `List<DataCategory>` values...

Comment: @AdrianLarson - you deleted the idea of getting the data via 'JSON.serialize(
      describeDataCategoryGroupSample()'  does this mean, this shouldn't be used / is not best practice? Sorry but I'm a kind of absolute beginner here...

Comment: Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask] and [answer]. You should never post an `Answer`which is actually just you asking something. That would only be appropriate as a `Comment` or separate `Question`.

Comment: Absolutely - fair enough. So what do you think, is this a proper way to solve the problem also: `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  public static String getDataTest() {return JSON.serialize(describeDataCategoryGroupSample());} `